# How to make a shape with 3 Faces from another shape that has more than 10 faces?

Tags: edit-mode, faces, extrude

I can't explain what I want at all, that's why I can't find a tutorial, I would like to make the end of my roof be with 3 faces like the second image, but without create a second model? THANKS

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would create the triangle mesh first, then subdivide each side of it as often as needed to have enough vertices along each of the three sides with which you can then merge the end vertices of your cylindrical part.

Comment: mhh, isn't there a way to do as on the first image and thanks to a modifier to change the shape? I tried decimate but it's not good

Comment: You could try shrink wrapping the vertical cylinder on the inside of the triangle